# Sharing data between HTML pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, data-sharing

I am kinf od new to the HTML relation and sharing stuff, I was wondering if I could share "large amount of data" between pages
I have a HTML that rapresents a shop, and when I select multiple itmes to add to the cart I take the image of it, the name, the quantity and pricy
Now, the question come obvious: How can I share all these informations from HTML pages using whatever is needed? (Such as PHP or JS) Can I do this in a separate pages? Can I share between pages, like, a  that has into it like some other HTML components?

I have looked for other solution that could help me but I found none

I thank whoever come and help me, if there is already a solution that I haven't seen, I apologize for writing this

Comment: This is often done using session variables in PHP. Or you could write the information to a database and use a session variable or a cookie to hold your reference to the database table.

Comment: So I can store variables into SQL and get them back with the second HTML page? But isn't required to load data with the page withour reloading it? Like, you load the data from the 1st HTML page to SQL, in the second one, you get the data from the same database, and you should have them without eny page refresh, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you've gone from one HTML page to a second one, you have a page refresh. But part of the opening of the second page could include retrieving the data from the database. Or from a session variable. Up to you.

Comment: Yes, that was what I mean, having the second HTML page with the content already retrieved from SQL

Comment: Your second page would be written in something like PHP. The PHP would retrieve the data from either the session array or the database, and then it would be responsible for displaying the HTML code and the various data items. I'm sure if you do a search on implementing a basic shopping cart there are plenty of articles describing it in detail. Just make sure they're up to date and use stuff like prepared statements and proper security.

Comment: I'll be checking all you aviced, thanks in avdance for al the help you gave me

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP and Session-Variables, that you fill with a HTML-Form. For example a - form method="POST" - with a - input name ="name" action="index.php".

---

//PHP file

session_start();

$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];

echo $_SESSION["name"];

---

The $_SESSION["name"] will be available on any page (under the same domain)!
The "session_start();" line has to be on top of every page in the php tag.

Be sure so secure the string before working with MySQL.

Comment: Seems what I will try yhen, but what if I have 3 or more forms, 2 of which are not with an imput parameter but more as a checkbox, and I have to pass all forms informations to another page, or, use the information I gathered trhought the forms to load new page content based on these infos, like you would do into a shop?

Comment: As long as all the pages have a `session_start()` at the beginning, your session variables should remain available through multiple pages, back and forwards. Have a try, it's easier to see.

Comment: @mirkodalfarra as far as i know, its only possible to supply 1 form at a time... checkbox parameters are no problem, their "value" behaves like text inputs.

Comment: What if I use some sort of JS that reload the content but not the page, with forms? AJAX kind of stuff? I have looked over some tutorial but I could not really understand

Comment: Ajax will work too, but you may want to consider people who have JavaScript disabled in their browsers, if people still do that.